# Hadoop MapReduce. Trouble opening file to pass parameters

Tags: file, hadoop, parameters, mapreduce

I'm trying to open a file to pass some parameters read in the file to the job MapReduce. This code works in local mode, but when i try to attack HDFS it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
Path tmpPath = new Path(tmpFile);
    try {
        InputStream ips = new FileInputStream(tmpFile);
        InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);

        String[] minMax = br.readLine().split("-");
        min = minMax[0];
        max = minMax[1];
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

This is the code error that appears:

> "java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/dataOut/tmp/part-r-00000 (No such file or directory)"

This is the place where i write the file in the previous job:

```
    Path tmp = new Path("dataOut/tmp");
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, tmp);
```

As MapReduce job, this will write the file part-r-00000.

Probably all of you will say, "Try with Distributed cache". 
I've already tried, but i'm newbie with Java, Hadoop and MapReduce. And i couldnt make it work...

Thanks

Comment: did you check whether that file is present in that path in hdfs ?

Comment: Yes, i already checked. It's there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. I used this code:

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Path file = new Path(DEFAULT_FS + "/user/cloudera/dataOut/tmp/part-r-00000");
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(file.toUri(), conf);
    FSDataInputStream in = hdfs.open(file);
    byte[] content = new byte[(int) hdfs.getFileStatus(file).getLen()];
    in.readFully(content);
    String maxMin = new String(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error code 
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: hdfs:/quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/dataOut/tmp/part-r-00000 (No such file or directory)"

It seems that your output path is not present in the given directory.
Try running the following command to check whether you are able to excess the path or not.

hadoop fs -text  hdfs:/quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/dataOut/tmp/part-r-00000

Comment: I've checked that and the file is up. I'm making a program with two Mapreduce jobs . The first create that file that the second try to get.

Comment: Is your tmpFile a hadoop path or local path. As you won't be able to read your hadoop path through FileInputStream.

Comment: I made first executions in local. It was a local path. After that i changed to HDFS path. My first job can write in that path. But the second job can't read that file.

Comment: Can you also post your code where you are writing that file to that path. And also the path where you are writing.

Comment: This is the place where i write the file in the previous job:

 Path tmp = new Path("dataOut/tmp");
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, tmp);

Probably you don't see the prefix, but it's the place where it write: hdfs:/quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/